can I get the approximately memory size in x86 without memory map
I know that in 32-bit protected mode in x86 the memory model is segmentation, so can I set GDT at base and at limit 4G, then accessing for example byte for first 1M then 2G or something like this, if accessing invalid physical address will trigger general protection fault but if I have set up IDT and no problem on it, the CPU  will not fall in double or triple fault so in this way I can the approximately memory size in protected mode, and there is no reason for the CPU to triple fault because the handler does not have problem or fault and the IDT is loaded so the fault is handled, can I use this way for get the size of memory.
